# Cannot compile, build c code using ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, gcc

can anyone tell me why I cannot compile my code? I know the program is working because I had it working on a different machine but I want to run it on Ubuntu.

[image: Terminal Log after attempt to build]

Comment: Those are not compiler errors, but *linker* errors, and you get them because you don't link with the required library for those functions. Try reading the manual pages for those functions to see what library you need to link with (or possibly other flags you need to provide when building).

Comment: If you do something like `man sem_wait` it clearly states *"Link with -pthread."*

Comment: Please copy/paste your errors as text, not as an image.